# Slow connection to Cassandra

Tags: java, php, cassandra, datastax

I have trouble connecting to my 3-node cassandra cluster via Datastax PHP- and Java-Driver.

Especially for the PHP driver it is crucial that i can connect fast to improve loading times of my website.

How can i debug this or what is the reason?

Java output shows this:

```
09:59:40,284 [main] DEBUG - com.datastax.driver.NEW_NODE_DELAY_SECONDS is undefined, using default value 1
09:59:40,284 [main] DEBUG - com.datastax.driver.NON_BLOCKING_EXECUTOR_SIZE is undefined, using default value 4
09:59:40,297 [main] DEBUG - com.datastax.driver.NOTIF_LOCK_TIMEOUT_SECONDS is undefined, using default value 60
09:59:40,357 [main] DEBUG - Starting new cluster with contact points [/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9042, /XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY:9042, /XXX.XXX.XXX.ZZZ:9042]
09:59:40,402 [main] DEBUG - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
09:59:40,489 [main] DEBUG - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
09:59:40,490 [main] DEBUG - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
09:59:40,490 [main] DEBUG - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
09:59:40,490 [main] DEBUG - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: true
09:59:40,492 [main] DEBUG - Java version: 8
09:59:40,492 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
09:59:40,492 [main] DEBUG - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
09:59:40,492 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.noJavassist: false
09:59:40,665 [main] DEBUG - Javassist: available
09:59:40,665 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /var/folders/4y/t4b47lbn1zjbjpb6x09l30wm0000gn/T (java.io.tmpdir)
09:59:40,666 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
09:59:40,666 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
09:59:40,708 [main] DEBUG - com.datastax.driver.FORCE_NIO is undefined, using default value false
09:59:40,710 [main] INFO  - Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
09:59:40,714 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 8
09:59:40,723 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
09:59:40,723 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
09:59:40,747 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel: simple
09:59:41,035 [main] DEBUG - com.datastax.driver.DISABLE_COALESCING is undefined, using default value false
09:59:41,046 [main] DEBUG - Generated: io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.com.datastax.driver.core.Message$ResponseMatcher
09:59:41,066 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 4
09:59:41,066 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 4
09:59:41,066 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
09:59:41,066 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
09:59:41,067 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
09:59:41,067 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512
09:59:41,067 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
09:59:41,067 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
09:59:41,067 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
09:59:41,067 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
09:59:41,078 [main] DEBUG - Generated: io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.com.datastax.driver.core.FrameMatcher
09:59:41,082 [main] DEBUG - Generated: io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.com.datastax.driver.core.Message$RequestMatcher
09:59:41,104 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier: 0x24d6f22f78c5a924 (took 8 ms)
09:59:41,130 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: unpooled
09:59:41,130 [main] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 65536
09:59:41,197 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG - Connection[/XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] Connection opened successfully
09:59:41,218 [cluster1-nio-worker-0] DEBUG - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacity.default: 262144
09:59:41,432 [main] DEBUG - [Control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
09:59:41,518 [main] DEBUG - [Control connection] Refreshing schema
09:59:42,137 [main] DEBUG - [Control connection] Refreshing node list and token map
09:59:42,315 [main] DEBUG - [Control connection] Successfully connected to /XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY:9042
09:59:42,315 [main] INFO  - Using data-center name '168' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)
09:59:42,315 [main] INFO  - New Cassandra host /XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9042 added
09:59:42,315 [main] INFO  - New Cassandra host /XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY:9042 added
09:59:42,315 [main] INFO  - New Cassandra host /XXX.XXX.XXX.ZZZ:9042 added
09:59:42,342 [cluster1-nio-worker-1] DEBUG - Connection[/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9042-2, inFlight=0, closed=false] Connection opened successfully
09:59:42,345 [cluster1-nio-worker-2] DEBUG - Connection[/XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] Connection opened successfully
09:59:42,348 [cluster1-nio-worker-3] DEBUG - Connection[/XXX.XXX.XXX.ZZZ:9042-1, inFlight=0, closed=false] Connection opened successfully
09:59:42,580 [cluster1-nio-worker-2] DEBUG - Added connection pool for /XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9042
09:59:42,591 [cluster1-nio-worker-3] DEBUG - Added connection pool for /XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY:9042
09:59:42,609 [cluster1-nio-worker-1] DEBUG - Added connection pool for /XXX.XXX.XXX.ZZZ:9042
```

As you can see, it takes ~2.5 seconds which is too slow for my use case.

Same happens with the PHP driver, but i don't have a log for this.

Queries are very fast once the driver is connected. Only issue is the slow connection time. I have set up all the three nodes as contact points.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify: My PHP driver is the problem. I'm wondering why it isn't using pooling/persisting connections. When i call the script two times in a row, every call takes 2-5 seconds. I think the second call should be using the persisting pool. phpinfo() shows persistent clusters & sessions = 0. This is the code that i'm using:

```
$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()
        ->withContactPoints('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY, 'XXX.XXX.XXX.ZZZ')
        ->withCredentials('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
        ->build();
$keyspace = 'myKeyspace';
$session = $cluster->connect($keyspace);
```

**UPDATE**

The problem was my network. Had too little bandwidth.

Comment: Please tell me what is wrong with my question when you vote it down.

Answer (score 1):

DataStax drivers are full featured drivers. They are aware of your custer topology and cluster state which requires some expensive operations in the cluster object build stage. It is common for the cluster object creation to take multiple seconds (depending on the size of your cluster/number of nodes).

The best practice is not to create the cluster object for every request (that would be extremely inefficient). Instead, you want to build the cluster object one time and maintain the connections open. Then when you receive a request from your front end, handle it with the existing cluster object.

Cassandra will give you very fast response times when used correctly.

For other c* client best practices, take a look at [Brian's Cassandra Loader](https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader). This is a good reference application as well as a very efficient bulk loader.

Some key best practices include: Limit the number of async requests if you are using execute async, if you are using batches, ensure that the batches are token specific to avoid excessive coordination, do not use logged batches unless you need atomicity, and do not dynamically manipulate your schema from your application to avoid schema mismatches.

Comment: Hi, this is very true. The question is, though, why my PHP instance has to reconnect every time when the driver is supposed to persist those connections? Just updated my question.